# Pyspark: withColumn looks for column although conditional tells it not to do so

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nested

I decided to open a new question because the other one, though related to this topic, is actually solved and flagged as such. Hope that is ok.
I am still trying to add a new column to a dataframe and the value of the column should either be a value from the source Json or Null (because not all source files contain all columns all the time).
I already created an extra column "SCHEMA" with

```
lit(df.schema.simpleString())
```

and I use it for the conditional in the following columns, such as:

```
.withColumn("STATUS_BIT", when(col("SCHEMA").contains("statusBit"), col("statusBit")).otherwise(None))
```

the good news is that the contains-condition delivers the right result. However, in case the condition is False, I get an error that tells me col(statusBit) is not in the source ("no such struct field..."). This is obviously the opposite of what I want to achieve, because the whole purpose of the effort is to insert a null value if the column is not in the schema.
Why does the when condition even look for col("statusBit"), although the condition says it is not there?
Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: please post a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a close ")" for the when clause. Please check if that is the issue. But in that case your command would have thrown an error in the first place.

```
.withColumn("STATUS_BIT", when(col("SCHEMA").contains("statusBit"), col("statusBit")).otherwise(None))
```

Comment: Hi greenie, thanks for your suggestion. That was just a typo I produced when writing down the code snippet. I jut fixed it in the original post